# Do we really need distinct tags for [attack] and [attack-roll]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonymization

[attack-roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-roll):

> For questions about attack rolls, a randomized event (usually performed with dice) that determines whether one character can strike another character or entity.

[attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack):

> For questions about attacks. An attack is an action that can be taken by a vast number of entities that either can cause damage, a debilitation of some sort, or both, though specific RPGs may define the term more specifically.

It seems to me that [attack-roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-roll) should be covered already by [attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack), so I don't see a use for having [attack-roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-roll) be its own thing. So I'm putting this forward for community discussion.

Answer (score 5):

### Let us keep them the way they are.

Not all questions tagged [attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack) include an [attack-roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-roll). Generally, we have a subset of specific questions explicitly about attack roll calculations or attack-roll interactions with other parts of respective game engines that are distinct enough from the broad category of the [attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack) tag.

Until someone demonstrates that the more specific [attack-roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-roll) causes confusion or other issues, there is no need to lose utility by merging a more specific distinct tag with a less specific one.

Comment: Not all systems that have attacks even use randomizers to determine the results.

Comment: And some systems have technical attack rolls that aren't part of an attack action, like for example Pathfinder's Combat Maneuvers technically use an attack roll (and all multipliers that trigger on that term).

Answer (score -5):

## Merge them

There is no reason to have a specific roll tag. We once had at least twice decided to [keep [attack] so now use it!](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/should-we-burninate-attack-and-damage?rq=1)